# How to extract the desired output from this json?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

json Input:

---

[
{
"brand": "mobile",
"qty": 245
},
{
"brand": "tablet",
"qty": 1202
},
{
"brand": "xbox",
"qty": 6031
}
]

Desired json output:

---

{
"mobile" : 245,
"tablet" : 1202,
"xbox"   : 6031
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator = {}) -> accumulator ++ 
    {(item.brand): item.qty}
)
```

This option uses the reduce function that accumulate the desired key:value pairs into an object.
You can learn more about it in the DataWeave Interactive Tutorial (section 7.5-reduce)

You could also use the object constructor after mapping the array as StackOverflowed proposed in his solution.

This has more info on Dynamic elements using the object constructor https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements

Comment: It is recommended to explain answers and not just link to external pages.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
  (payload map 
    ($.brand): $.qty // Iterate over and map brand key's value with qty key's value
  )
} // to enclose output within an object
```